# How to refresh a WMS layer in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have a wms layer, created like so:

```
layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  visible: true,
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
      url: 'http://localhost:8085/geoserver/accent/wms',
      params: {
          'FORMAT': 'image/png', 
          'VERSION': '1.1.1',
           tiled: true,
           STYLES: '',
           LAYERS: 'accent:layer_' + layer_id + '_',
           tilesOrigin: 0 + "," + 0.0000000000014415
      }
   })
});
```

I have some buttons in my application, that enable to change the layer store (make a shift, increase number of levels for tiles etc.). So, to make these changes visible, I need a method to "refresh" the layer, so that it would make server requests and redraw itself. It seems, like in old OL2 there was a nice method:

```
myWMSLayer.redraw(true);
```

But I do not know how can I achieve the same effect in OL3. Thanks!

Comment: Or probably there is a parameter to disable caching on the GeoServer side. Now the tiles are cached, even if I add some random parameter to params block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve that, you can use the [updateParams](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.TileWMS.html#updateParams) on the layer source

```
var params = layer.getSource().getParams();
layer.getSource().updateParams(params);
```

Comment: It doesn't work on my side. Not for wms-layer on OL3.

Answer (score 1):

Because the WMS layer will refresh when you zoom in/out I managed to make it refresh by zooming the map slightly when I needed it to update.

```
var current_zoom = map.getView().getZoom();
map.getView().setZoom(current_zoom - 0.001);
```